# Drush broke after upgrading to OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, mamp, drush

After upgrading to OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) from OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion), Drush broke. I've MAMP.

The error message when I invoke drush:

```
Could not open input file: /usr/lib/php/pear/drush/drush.php
```

I've put the below in .bash_profile

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3.20/bin:$PATH"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OSX Mavericks has no PEAR (and your Drush is probably gone too).

Install PEAR -

```
sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 /usr/lib/php/install-pear-nozlib.phar
```

Install Drush -

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.drush.org
sudo pear install drush/drush
```

Run Drush as root once so Drush installs Console::Getopt etc.

```
sudo drush help
```

Answer (score 0):

[Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) is probably a better way of managing Drush in Mac OS now.

Heres how it relates to Drush https://drupal.org/node/954766